# Python Scipy FFT to determine the interval with the more high frequency signals

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have a problem that I am trying to solve. I have a Depth, GR, Facies values that stand for the depth at which a sample is taken, the Gamma value of it , and the Rock type.
I am trying to the set a moving window (30 ft, 15ft above and 15ft below) and find out which interval has the most high frequencies of layering/interbedding in them. And interbedding is determined by different rock types that are reflected by the gamma ray value.

So I thought I will employ the scipy fft on the Gamma Ray to establish its frequency and amplitude for every moving interval and then compute the p90 values (?? I dont know if this is the right way) of all the frequencies encountered. What I expected was a continuous curve indicating the highest frequency values, but I got something else. There were several nan (+/-). Here is the code I have so far.

```
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
logs_dict ={'Depth': [7075.0, 7075.5, 7076.0, 7076.5, 7077.0, 7077.5, 7078.0, 7078.5, 7079.0, 7079.5, 7080.0, 7080.5, 7081.0, 7081.5, 7082.0, 7082.5, 7083.0, 7083.5, 7084.0, 7084.5, 7085.0, 7085.5, 7086.0, 7086.5, 7087.0, 7087.5, 7088.0, 7088.5, 7089.0, 7089.5, 7090.0, 7090.5, 7091.0, 7091.5, 7092.0, 7092.5, 7093.0, 7093.5, 7094.0, 7094.5, 7095.0, 7095.5, 7096.0, 7096.5, 7097.0, 7097.5, 7098.0, 7098.5, 7099.0, 7099.5, 7100.0, 7100.5, 7101.0, 7101.5, 7102.0, 7102.5, 7103.0, 7103.5, 7104.0, 7104.5, 7105.0, 7105.5, 7106.0, 7106.5, 7107.0, 7107.5, 7108.0, 7108.5, 7109.0, 7109.5, 7110.0, 7110.5, 7111.0, 7111.5, 7112.0, 7112.5, 7113.0, 7113.5, 7114.0, 7114.5, 7115.0, 7115.5, 7116.0, 7116.5, 7117.0, 7117.5, 7118.0, 7118.5, 7119.0, 7119.5, 7120.0, 7120.5, 7121.0, 7121.5, 7122.0, 7122.5, 7123.0, 7123.5, 7124.0, 7124.5, 7125.0, 7125.5, 7126.0, 7126.5, 7127.0, 7127.5, 7128.0, 7128.5, 7129.0, 7129.5, 7130.0, 7130.5, 7131.0, 7131.5, 7132.0, 7132.5, 7133.0, 7133.5, 7134.0, 7134.5, 7135.0, 7135.5, 7136.0, 7136.5, 7137.0, 7137.5, 7138.0, 7138.5, 7139.0, 7139.5, 7140.0, 7140.5, 7141.0, 7141.5, 7142.0, 7142.5, 7143.0, 7143.5, 7144.0, 7144.5, 7145.0, 7145.5, 7146.0, 7146.5, 7147.0, 7147.5, 7148.0, 7148.5, 7149.0, 7149.5, 7150.0, 7150.5, 7151.0, 7151.5, 7152.0, 7152.5, 7153.0, 7153.5, 7154.0, 7154.5, 7155.0, 7155.5, 7156.0, 7156.5, 7157.0, 7157.5, 7158.0, 7158.5, 7159.0, 7159.5, 7160.0, 7160.5, 7161.0, 7161.5, 7162.0, 7162.5, 7163.0, 7163.5, 7164.0, 7164.5, 7165.0, 7165.5, 7166.0, 7166.5, 7167.0, 7167.5, 7168.0, 7168.5, 7169.0, 7169.5, 7170.0, 7170.5, 7171.0, 7171.5, 7172.0, 7172.5, 7173.0, 7173.5, 7174.0, 7174.5, 7175.0], 'GR': [35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 35, 35, 35, 35, 110, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 55, 55, 55, 140, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15, 15, 135, 15], 'Facies': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]}

logs=pd.DataFrame(logs_dict)
target_window = 30
logs=logs.reset_index()
data_freq=logs[['GR']]
for i in range(0, len(logs)):
    if i <= target_window:
        logs.at[i, 'Interbedding'] =0
    elif i > (len(logs)-target_window):
        logs.at[i, 'Interbedding'] = 0
    else:
        data =data_freq.iloc[int(i-target_window/2):int(i+target_window/2),].values
        time_step=data[1]-data[0]
        ps = np.abs(fftpack.fft(data))
        freq = fftpack.fftfreq(data.size,time_step)
        freq=freq[:data.size//2]
        value=np.percentile(freq, 90)*2000
        logs.at[i, 'Interbedding'] =value

facies_colors = ['darkviolet', 'lightgreen', 'r','yellow','navy','coral']
cmap_facies = colors.ListedColormap(
    facies_colors[0:len(facies_colors)], 'indexed')
cluster=np.repeat(np.expand_dims(logs['Facies'].values,1), 100, 1)

#Plotting the results 
f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(5, 9))
f.subplots_adjust(top=0.75, wspace=0.1)
for i in range(len(ax) - 1):
    ax[i].set_ylim(top, bottom)
    ax[i].invert_yaxis()
    ax[i].grid()
    ax[i].locator_params(axis='x', nbins=3)
ax00=ax[0].twiny()
ax00.plot(logs.GR, logs.Depth, '-g', alpha=0.8, lw=0.9)
ax41 = ax[1].twiny()
ax41.plot(logs.Interbedding, logs.Depth, '-k', alpha=0.8, lw=0.9)
ax61 = ax[2].twiny()
ax61.imshow(cluster, interpolation='none', aspect='auto',cmap=cmap_facies, vmin=0, vmax=5)
ax00.spines['top'].set_position(('outward', 0))
ax00.set_xlabel('GR', color='green')
ax00.set_xlim(0, 150)
ax41.set_xlabel("Interbedding",color='b')
ax41.set_xlim(0,25)
ax61.spines['top'].set_position(('outward',0))
ax61.set_xlabel('Facies')
ax[1].set_yticklabels([]); ax[2].set_yticklabels([])
ax[1].set_xticklabels([]); ax[2].set_xticklabels([])
ax[0].set_xticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

This is what I get. What I am looking is a continuous curve that will indicate to me which interval has higher frequencies. Where are am i going wrong? I dont have signal analysis background. I am trying to see if I can apply this concept here. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure FFT is the right solution for you.   This is artificial data, of course, but that curve has a complicated frequency signature.  I might suggest you think about counting the zero crossings instead.  Subtract the average of GR from GR, then count where it changes sign.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it. the only issue was I could have the same number of zero crossing between two intervals but at different frequencies.. I want to distinguish them. Don't know how

Comment: Actually, you can't.  The very definition of the "frequency" is the number of zero crossings.

Comment: what I am trying to say is ..suppose the window length is 20ft. Once scenario, there is no zero crossing for the first 10 ft and then in the next 10 ft there are 10 zero crossings with 1ft intervals for a total of 10 zero crossing in 20 ft. Second scenario is 10 zero crossing with 2ft intervals within 20 ft. Even though they have the same number of zero crossing, they do not have the same frequencies.

Comment: Actually, over that entire interval, they DO have the same frequency.  That's the difficulty you have.  And it is extremely unlikely that your real data has such a regular pattern.  Maybe you need to compute the delta between zero crossings and look for trends in that signal.  Kind of like the first derivative.